# How to know which win handle will get the focus when clicked?

Tags: c#, winapi, window, handle

So it's definetely a weird question. When a window is on the background, it has no focus. But when you click on it, it get it and the "keyboard cursor" is placed in a specific place. For example, if you are using Skype, the keyboard cursor will be inside the textbox of the active conversation. In Skype, the textbox has its specific handle.

So the question is: How to know which window handle will be focused when you click on the main (parent) window title?

Regards

EDIT1:

I found a workaround for my case: I want to register inside a variable, each handle code of the last window of each main window. For example, I have 3 opened windows, the one with arrow is focused:

1.)

->Window 1
  ->Child window1
  -Child window2
-Window 2
-Window 3

2.) I select another window, so the handle number of the child window that lost focus is saved inside a variable

-Window 1
  -Child window1
  -Child window2
->Window 2
-Window 3

=> HANDLE OF Child window1 is saved inside a variable

Using this, I could know the last used window's handle of each application! Is there any way to generate an event each time the user change the focused window handle? Or do I need to set a timer, that is not really clever to my mind?

Regards

Comment: This is a decision internal to the program. When you click on the window, the program decides which window gets focus. To get the answer without actually clicking on the window, you will have to design a private communication channel with the program.

Comment: Is it complicated to do?

Comment: It's as complicated as you want to make it. You could define a private message that both sides agree upon.

Comment: Any link to a tutorial or an explaination? I found nothing with these keywords on google.

Comment: There is no tutorial for this. It's just custom code. You might agree for example that the message WM_APP+8 means "tell me what window you are going to give focus to when you are activated."

Comment: So do I need to use RegisterWindowMessage?

Comment: You can use any mechanism you want, as long as both sides of the interface agree on it.

Comment: So it cannot work then. Indeed, I want to postmessage to Skype for example.

Comment: Let's step back. Why do you need to do this? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Not sure whether this question is still alive, but there is an event when the user changes the focused window. Take a look at **SetWinEventHook** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the SystemEvent **EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for these links. I will investigate to determine if it does work. Thank you very much